# How to use radio button in a form that passes a value in the URL GET vs POST

Tags: php, sql, forms, radio-button

Working out a simple star ratings script. Data not inserting into SQL. I am passing a 'id' in  the url from the form action to coincide with the rating. I'm using GET to retreive that value. I'm using POST to insert the radio button value. I've tested and the url is passing the id. The script runs to completion. SQL is connecting.

index.html

```
    <form method="POST" action="rating.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
      <fieldset class="rating">
          <legend>. . .</legend>
              <input type="radio" id="star3" name="starno" value="3" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
                  <label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
              <input type="radio" id="star2" name="starno" value="2" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
                  <label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
              <input type="radio" id="star1" name="starno" value="1" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
                  <label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

ratings.php

```
    <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors','1');
    isset($_GET['id']);
    $storyidr = $_GET['id'];
    $star = $_POST['starno'];
    $con=mysqli_connect ("","","","");
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO ratings (storyidr,rank,entry_date)';
    $sql .= 'VALUES("'.$storyidr.'","'.$star.'",now())';
    mysqli_close($con);
        print_r(array_keys(get_defined_vars()));
        print_r(array_values(get_defined_vars()));
    ?>
```

SQL

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ratings` 
    (
      `ratingid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `storyidr` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
      `rank` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `entry_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ratingid`),
    UNIQUE KEY `ratingid` (`ratingid`)
    ) 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='rating for stories' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

error report

( [affected_rows] => [client_info] => [client_version] => 50532 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => [error] => [error_list] => [field_count] => [host_info] => [info] => [insert_id] => [server_info] => [server_version] => [stat] => [sqlstate] => [protocol_version] => [thread_id] => [warning_count] => ) [7] => INSERT INTO ratings (storyidr,rank,entry_date)VALUES("198","3",now()) )

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Why aren't you [testing for SQL errors](http://uk1.php.net/mysqli_error) ?

Comment: added error testing, wasn't informative. SQL is connecting, data just not inderting

Comment: You don’t execute the query.

Comment: needed execution. thanks Gumbo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are connected to DB where is rating table, table exist, php work fine, id is passing, mysqli_connect is connected then maybe a space before VALUES like this:

```
 $sql .= ' VALUES("'.$storyidr.'","'.$star.'",now())';
```

as i'm aware code which U have right now is not valid

```
INSERT INTO ratings (storyidr,rank,entry_date)VALUES("'.$storyidr.'","'.$star.'",now())
```

/// edited to add some security ;)

Use PDO to handle with MySQL all time:

```
try {
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=local;dbname=db','user','pass');
$pdo->setAsttribute(PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO ratings SET name = :name, surname = :surname';
$oo_db = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$oo_db->bindValue(':surname', $surname);
$oo_db->execute();
  }
catch (PDOException $e) { $error = "fail"; }
```

more at -> http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Positional-and-Named-Placeholders-P551.html